# selenium webdriver terminates execution if element not found

Tags: php, selenium-webdriver

**Following is the php code i have used to post data on some third party site using selenium web driver**

```
$webdriver = new WebDriver("localhost", "4444");
$webdriver->connect("firefox");
 try{       
        $webdriver->get(trim($push[$key]['app']));
        sleep(4);
        if($webdriver->findElementBy(LocatorStrategy::xpath,'//a[@ng-click="vm.isEditorEdit=true;"]')){
            $editBtn=$webdriver-findElementBy(LocatorStrategy::xpath,'//a[@ng-click="vm.isEditorEdit=true;"]');
            $editBtn->click();
            sleep(2);
        }
        $pushTitle=$webdriver-findElementBy(LocatorStrategy::xpath,'//input[1]');
        $pushTitle->sendKeys(array($push[$key]['title']));
        $webdriver-executeScript("tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent('".$push[$key]['message']."')",array());
        $sendBtn=$webdriver-findElementBy(LocatorStrategy::xpath,'//a[@id="sendButton"]');
        $sendBtn->click();      sleep(2);
        if($webdriver->findElementBy(LocatorStrategy::xpath,'//a[@ng-click="onSave();"]'))
        {
            $sureBtn=$webdriver-findElementBy(LocatorStrategy::xpath,'//a[@ng-click="onSave();"]');
            $sureBtn->click();
            sleep(5);
        }
    }catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n"; 
    }
```

see there are two elements ($editBtn,$sureBtn ) which are not be there always , so that i have put them in

> if condition

code is working fine if  $editBtn and $sureBtn are presented on the page that i used to post data otherwise terminates with error "Caught exception: No such element exception" but  script should not terminate.

please suggest me solution.

Thanks.

Comment: "but script should not terminate" --- what makes you thinking so?

Comment: if i just add a post in "some third party site" and again adding new post with in 30 minutes third party site alerting me with popup confirm box **Are you sure to post ,you just posted** in this case i have to click button with WD if no confirmation box script let me proceed , but terminates with no (sure button)such element found. got my point ?? @zerkms

Comment: I don't sorry. If the exception states there is no such element - I don't see any reason to not trust it.

Comment: There are multiple post will be posting with the script.If execution terminates while posting first post in that case other posts are not posting.This is the problem @zerkms